# primeng tabview scroll arrows not showing

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, primeng

I need to fix a problem that invokes primeng's resize binding method. The issue is with the following method:

```
bindResizeObserver() {
        this.container = DomHandler.findSingle(this.el.nativeElement, '[data-pc-section="navcontent"]');
        this.list = DomHandler.findSingle(this.el.nativeElement, '[data-pc-section="nav"]');
        this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
            if (this.list.offsetWidth > this.container.offsetWidth) {
                this.buttonVisible = true;
            }
            else {
                this.buttonVisible = false;
            }
            this.updateButtonState();
            this.cd.detectChanges();
        });
        this.resizeObserver.observe(this.container);
    }
```

It returns always false. My thought is to always add 1 px to the inner element's width so the condition is always true. How can I always add 1 px to the width of the list element